# Powershell errors in azure functions when running R scripts

Tags: r, powershell, azure, azure-functions

I am currently deploying an R microservice to azure functions but I am running into some issues.
I installed the R executable from the azure site extensions and I am running my R script with this R executable using PowerShell.

The script runs entirely but I get some strange errors that don't seem to come from my R script, but are specific PowerShell errors.
Here are the logs I get:

```
2018-06-11T15:37:14.373 [Info] PowerShell Timer trigger function executed at:06/11/2018 15:37:14

2018-06-11T15:37:17.924 [Info] [1] "Retrieving data"

2018-06-11T15:37:18.158 [Error] D:\home\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe : Loading required package: methods

at run.ps1: line 4

+ D:\home\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe

+ ___________________________________

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Loading required package: methods:String) [], RemoteException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError


at run.ps1: line 4

+ D:\home\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe

+ ___________________________________

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RemoteException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandErrorMessage


at run.ps1: line 4

+ D:\home\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe

+ ___________________________________

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RemoteException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandErrorMessage

2018-06-11T15:37:20.837 [Info] [1] "Finished retrieving data, computing first function"

2018-06-11T15:37:21.040 [Info] [1] "2nd function.."

2018-06-11T15:37:21.040 [Info] [1] "3rd function.."

2018-06-11T15:37:21.061 [Info] [1] "last function.."

2018-06-11T15:37:21.061 [Info] [1] "Finished everything"


at run.ps1: line 4

+ D:\home\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe

+ ___________________________________

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RemoteException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandErrorMessage

2018-06-11T15:37:21.290 [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerEngagement. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: PowerShell script error. Loading required package: methods.

2018-06-11T15:37:21.337 [Error] Function completed (Failure, Id=..., Duration=7114ms)
```

My PowerShell script run is simply:

```
cd D:\home\site\wwwroot\microservices
D:\home\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe engagement.r
```

When I run my script inside of RStudio for example, I have no warning/error.
Any clues ? An explanation of these errors ?

**Edit (Answer)**

As ahmelsayed pointed out, this is an odd behavior of powershell in azure. By running some tests, a code as simple as

```
library('httr')
library('parsedate')
library('jsonlite')
print('Testing the azure functions')

for (i in 1:10){
    print(i)
}
```

returns

```
2018-06-18T09:43:08.204 [Error] D:\home\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe : Loading required package: methods

at run.ps1: line 4

+ D:\home\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe

+ ___________________________________

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Loading required package: methods:String) [], RemoteException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

2018-06-18T09:43:09.003 [Info] [1] "Testing the azure functions"

2018-06-18T09:43:09.048 [Info] [1] 1

2018-06-18T09:43:09.048 [Info] [1] 2

2018-06-18T09:43:09.048 [Info] [1] 3

2018-06-18T09:43:09.048 [Info] [1] 4

2018-06-18T09:43:09.048 [Info] [1] 5

2018-06-18T09:43:09.048 [Info] [1] 6

2018-06-18T09:43:09.048 [Info] [1] 7

2018-06-18T09:43:09.048 [Info] [1] 8

2018-06-18T09:43:09.081 [Info] [1] 9

2018-06-18T09:43:09.081 [Info] [1] 10

2018-06-18T09:43:09.173 [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerTest. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: PowerShell script error. Loading required package: methods.

2018-06-18T09:43:09.220 [Error] Function completed (Failure, Id=..., Duration=5223ms)
```

It seems that just loading a few packages in R and running simple code generates an error in Powershell, even if all packages are loaded correctly and the code runs fine.

Comment: Can you post *engagement.r* script or at least a small enough example to reproduce? Also use `cat` in R over `print` to avoid the vector `[1]` outputs. Other than log files, does the console show anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just odd behavior from powershell depending on the io host it's using. see this question and the accepted answer [Error when calling 3rd party executable from Powershell when using an IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2095088/3234163)