# How to print or log from Python under Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, scripting, output

I have a simple python script

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
print ("Hello, " + name)
```

saved to `test.py`

I have a simple powershell script

```
python test.py
```

saved to `Untitled2.ps1`

Running `Untitled2.ps1` from either the Powershell IDE or the command line cause no printing of the input request and no output. It hangs and has to be cancelled out. Entering data and pressing Return also cause no output.

Python 3.8.0, Windows 10, Powershell 5.1

Comment: Please edit the question so that contains only single an issue. Post either running the script or about the NativeCommandError part as a new one. For the latter, see if [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2095088/503046) helps.