# python prompt in Power Shell, and it is NOT a path issue

Tags: python

Python in Power shell: cannot bring up a >>> python prompt even if I start powershell in the directory where python.exe is.  This is not a PATH issue.  It seems that python is opened but doesnt run. This is what I get:

```
PS C:\Users\cohen\appdata\local\programs\python\python310> python
python : Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Python 3.10.5 (...MD64)] on win32:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Please share what you've already researched; I can find a lot of results, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20950421/6273251), when searching the error, but it would be a waste of all our time if I suggested something you'd done before. Please help us not waste our time by sharing what you've attempted to do to solve this.

Comment: are you using ISE or plain PowerShell? Try regular PowerShell. Do you get the same issue?

Comment: It very much runs Python, it just is *also* showing the errors.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use 64 bit python on 32 bit windows.