# Suppress NativeCommandError output when redirecting stdout and stderr to separate files

Tags: powershell, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

I have the following files:

**test.ps1**

```
& e:\test.bat > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt
```

**test.bat**

```
@echo off
echo write to stdout
echo write to stderr >&2
```

When I call `test.ps1` like this:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy bypass e:\test.ps1
```

The output files look like this:

**stdout.txt**

```
write argument to stdout
```

**stderr.txt**

```
test.bat : write to stderr 
At E:\test.ps1:5 char:1
+ & "$application" "$argument" > $stdout 2> $stderr
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (write to stderr :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

[There is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20950421/1728830) how to prevent the NativeCommandError output from being written to file when redirecting both stdout and stderr to the same file, but how can I achieve that when writing to different files?

Comment: If you can, upgrade to [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), which fixes the NativeCommandError issue.

Comment: @zett42 Oh, that's good to know! Alas I'm not sure what version of PowerShell runs on the users' PCs that this piece of PowerShell should work on.

Comment: Unfortunately, PS 7+ doesn't come with the OS by default, it has to be installed explicitly. So if they are on Windows 10, they will have PowerShell 5.1 only.

Comment: So the expected here would be to `stderr.txt` not be created, since it's a `NativeCommandError` ? If so, why not redirect both outputs to success and then filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on the helpful comments:

- In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, your command would work as expected.
- In *Windows PowerShell*, unfortunately, stderr lines are implicitly formatted *as if they were PowerShell errors* when a `2>` redirection is involved, resulting in the noisy output you saw.

The solution is to merge stderr into stdout with `2>&1`, and separate the collected lines into stdout and stderr by their type, allowing you to stringify the stderr lines, which PowerShell wraps in [`[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances, via their `.ToString()` method, which results in their text content only.

Apart from being cumbersome, this approach requires collecting all output in memory first.

```bash
$stdout, $stderr = (& e:\test.bat 2>&1).Where({ $_ -is [string] }, 'Split')

$stdout > stdout.txt
$stderr.ForEach('ToString') > stderr.txt
```

Comment: `$stderr.ForEachObject('ToString') > stderr.txt` gives me the error `Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] does not contain a method named
'ForEachObject'`. But based on this, I found a working solution: `foreach ($err in $stderr) { "$err" >> stderr.txt }`. I did not expect that it would write only the actual message without `.ToString()`, but it does.

Comment: Sorry, @ThomasW , that was a typo. Please see my update.

Comment: @ThomasW, enclosing a variable reference in “….” Is essentially the same as calling.ToString() on it.

Comment: There are some differences though, e. g. arrays just print the type when using `.ToString()`, but are joined when doing `"$array"`. Do you know if and where these differences are documented?

Comment: @zett42, yea, there are differences, not only with respect to arrays but also in that implicit stringification, such as in expandable strings and with `[string]` casts uses  culture-_invariant_ representations. In short, it is the equivalent of calling the stringification PowerShell performs is the equivalent of calling `.psobject.ToString([NullString]::Value, [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)` on a value, from what I can tell. I don't know of any official documentation, but I have summarized my own findings in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).

Answer (score 3):

Complementing mklement0's [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73594732/7571258), here is a function `Tee-StdErr` for PowerShell 5 and older versions that you can chain in-between to redirect stderr to a file without `NativeCommandError`, while forwarding regular output to the next pipeline command (or redirect it to a file if `>` is used):

```
Function Tee-StdErr {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)] $InputObject
    )

    begin {
        $file = if( $item = New-Item -Path $Path -Force ) { 
            [IO.StreamWriter]::new( $item.FullName ) 
        }
    }
    process {
        if( $InputObject -is [Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] ) {
            # stringify error message and write to file
            if( $file ) { $file.WriteLine( "$InputObject" ) }   
        }
        else { 
            # pass stdout through
            $InputObject   
        }  
    }
    end {
        $file | ForEach-Object Dispose
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
& .\test.bat 2>&1 | Tee-StdErr stderr.txt > stdout.txt

# Alternatively pipe stdout to other commands:
& .\test.bat 2>&1 | Tee-StdErr stderr.txt | Set-Content stdout.txt
```

- `2>&1` merges the error (`#2`) stream with the success (`#1`) stream, so both can be processed by the next pipeline command
- `Tee-StdErr` tests whether the current pipeline object (`$InputObject`) is an `ErrorRecord` and if so, it stringifies (`"$_"`) it and writes it to the error file. Otherwise the current object is a string from the success stream which is passed through by using PowerShell's *implicit output* feature (just naming the variable outputs it).