# Why following PowerShell show error after add redirection at the end of line?

Tags: shell, powershell, command-line, command, powershell-3.0

I have an python script which will invoke the `nmake`. I want to invoke this script in powershell as following.

```
python D:\build.py -f folder
```

It works fine and the output is as following:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.50727.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

But if I add the redirection to make all the `stderr&stdout` goes to `build.log` as following, it show red errors:

```
python D:\build.py -f folder 2>&1 | tee build.log

python :
At line:1 char:1
+ python D:\source_code\media\media\build_system\build.py -f xplatform_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.50727.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

---- Edit 1----

I understand possible reason is the external `nmake` executable write to `stderr`, then Powershell show error.

But the first example, which without redirection, doesn't show error. And the second one, which have redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, actually show errors. So any reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PsExec Throws Error Messages, but works without any problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380227/psexec-throws-error-messages-but-works-without-any-problems)

Comment: but I have redirect stderr, and the first code snippets doesn't show err

Comment: Ok, i got it. The redirect in Powershell is redirect object, not text. And the ErrorRecord object still got print even in stdout.

Comment: So how can I mark this post as close?

Comment: Write an answer yourself and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to answere my question so it can be closed and helpful for others.

The reason it show error is because the `ErrorRecord` object are print in `stdout`.

And the `2>&1` redirect the object instead of text. So after add the redirection, the `ErrorRecord` are redirect to `stdout`.

More information can be found at: [$LastExitCode=0 but $?=False in PowerShell. Redirecting stderr to stdout gives NativeCommandError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666101/lastexitcode-0-but-false-in-powershell-redirecting-stderr-to-stdout-gives-n)