# Python running from power-shell after correctly setting path variable, still fails to start and appears frozen

Tags: python, powershell, variables, path

I started here from this guide, Zed Shaw's guide for Learning Python the Hard Way. Came here reading a similar issue regarding the path variable, solved it by reinstalling the application and manually selecting to install path variable as an added option. (it was red, marked for exclusion) I also believe that setting it in power-shell worked too but was unsure until I did this.

My issue is when I now run python, it just sits there. Appears frozen, cmd prompt is not responsive and I have go hit the red square box to stop it. "stop operation, control + break"

This is the message it gives,

python : Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 
bit (AMD64)] on win32
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Python 2.7.13 (...MD64)] on win32:String) 
    [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

(>>>) -sits here.

-- And nothing can be done at this point until I hit red square box to stop it, also of note for a brief moment after typing python enter, it opens a secondary window which immediately closes. I have also ran powershell as admin, still no change.

Update, I have this exact same issue on the desktop. And If I try this in ms cmd prompt, python.. no issue. Loads up fine With a blinking prompt that is ready.

Comment: Could you post the output of:

1. `where.exe python*"`

2. `python -v`

Answer (score 3):

You must be using PowerShell ISE, where this is a known issue! E.g. [Python Interpreter crashing in Powershell ISE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548465/python-interpreter-crashing-in-powershell-ise)

You can, however, use regular PowerShell console and launch Python within that console.

Comment: @ZacCarter you're welcome. Please feel free to mark your question answered.