# Running Python Script under Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

Why does running a python script under powershell with logging enabled show below (standard python logging module)

```
python : INFO:root:File Creation Started at 18-Aug-2020
At C:\Untitled1.ps1:17 char:5
+     python "File Creation.py" $OracleDate
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (INFO:root:XXXX... at 18-Aug-2020:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
INFO:root:Running query SELECT * FROM reporting
INFO:root:18216 records saved to .txt
INFO:root:Running query SELECT * FROM reporting
INFO:root:18216 records saved to .txt
INFO:root:Running query SELECT * FROM reporting.
INFO:root:11322 records saved to .txt
INFO:root:Running query SELECT * from reporting
INFO:root:18216 records saved to .txt
INFO:root:Running query SELECT * FROM reporting
INFO:root:18216 records saved to .txt
```

The script runs and does what is required and prints out all the required message but why the error? Would like to get rid of the error message.

Looks like a possible Execution-Policy but I tried running this at Administrator privileges with same result?

Python 3.8.0, Windows 10, Powershell 5.1

Comment: What is the content of  `C:\Untitled1.ps1`? (at least first 20 lines or so)

Answer (score 1):

Something in the Python script writes into `stderr`, which Powershell interprets as an error condition. This is discussed in [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2095088/503046) in two previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1394084/503046). Without seeing the actual code, it's hard to say which part writes into error stream.

As a work-around, try to redirect error stream. In Powershell, `2> $null` [redirects error stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7) into `null`. It's possible to combine stderr and stdout with `2>&1`.

Maybe invoking the script with redirection would work. Like so,

```
python "File Creation.py" $OracleDate 1> output.log 2>&1
```

It seems that one can [redirect the stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1956142/503046) in Python, so it might be worth trying those solutions too. See all the answers, there are multiple approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to vonPryz. Link to the second question had an answer that helped.

This is a bug under Powershell ISE but runs fine under powershell command-line (i.e. not ISE)