# When running a powershell script via Jenkins getting this error : "NativeCommandError" not sure how to use invoke-command

Tags: powershell, error-handling, invoke-command

[Ignoring an errorlevel != 0 in Windows PowerShell (ISE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394084/ignoring-an-errorlevel-0-in-windows-powershell-ise)

I have read this link but not sure how to run "Invoke-Command" my $ErrorActionPreference is "continue".

This is the error I am getting :

```
06:06:55  + & powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command '& ''E: ...
06:06:55  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
06:06:55      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (root : 2020-10-...something:String) [], RemoteException
06:06:55      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$errorActionPreference` should be defined inside the scriptblock like:

```
Invoke-Command {$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; REST OF THE CODE}
```

Comment: how this will run on Jenkins descriptive style "Jenkinsfile", I have used this:
powershell (Invoke-Command {$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; "my code" })
This gives me error :
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Invoke for class: WorkflowScript
07:39:35   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
07:39:35   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:355)